# Verificar que un valor existen en un JSON localStorage

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

Quiero que al hacer click en un boton primero verifique si el valor existe en un JSON que obtiene desde localStorage y si no existe lo guarde, pero cuando realiza la funcion aunque el valor exista sigue añadiendo el arreglo. La funcion es:

```
$('#btnNP').click(function(){
        if ($.trim($('#txtplayer').val())==''){         
            alert('Ingresa tu nombre de jugador');
            $('#txtpalabra').focus();
            return false;
        }

        var jugador =$('#txtplayer').val();

        for(var i in Jugadores)
        {
            var con = JSON.parse(Jugadores[i]);
            if(con[i].player === j){
            console.log(con[i].player); 
            }
            if(con.player == jugador){
                console.log(con.player);
            }
            else{
                var jugador_push = JSON.stringify({
                    "player" : jugador,
                    "score" : 0
                });
                Jugadores.push(jugador_push);
                localStorage.setItem("Jugadores", JSON.stringify(Jugadores));
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Buenas, podrías agregar lo que estas obteniendo en la consola? para entender más o menos que valor tienen `con.player` y `jugador` y contra que lo estas comparando en `if(con.player == jugador)`

Y solo por curiosidad, no tendrías que hacer un  `Jugadores = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Jugadores")) ` antes del for? para llenar la variable con la ultima actualización?

Comment: Principalmente esta duplicando los valores (si tengo un registro, lo duplica 1 vez y si intento consultar el mismo valor y esta 2 veces los duplica dandome 4 registros y asi sucesivamente). Este es el JSON que imprime: `["{"player":"leader","score":0}", "{"player":"leader","score":0}", "{"player":"leader","score":0}", "{"player":"lel","score":0}", "{"player":"lel","score":0}", "{"player":"lel","score":0}", "{"player":"lel","score":0}", "{"player":"lol","score":0}", "{"player":"lol","score":0}", "{"player":"lol","score":0}", "{"player":"leader","score":0}", "{"player":"lel","score":0}"]`

Comment: Lo de parsear el JSON si lo hago, al principio del documento:
`var Jugadores = localStorage.getItem("Jugadores");`
`Jugadores = JSON.parse(Jugadores);`

Comment: Lo tengo, dejame subirlo a un fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Bien, disculpa la demora, el Fiddle no me dejó compartirlo así que lo puse en un [CodePen](https://codepen.io/tppshaka77/pen/zaoebv):

Esta así:

```js
// find elements
var button = $("button")

window.localStorage.setItem("Jugadores","[]"); 

// handle click and add class
button.on("click", function(){
   if ($.trim($('#txtplayer').val())==''){         
            alert('Ingresa tu nombre de jugador');
            $('#txtpalabra').focus();
            return false;
        }

        var jugador =$('#txtplayer').val();
        var Jugadores = localStorage.getItem("Jugadores"); 
        Jugadores = JSON.parse(Jugadores);
        
        if(Jugadores.length == 0)
        {
         var jugador_push = JSON.stringify({
                    "player" : jugador,
                    "score" : 0
                });
                Jugadores.push(jugador_push);
                localStorage.setItem("Jugadores", JSON.stringify(Jugadores));
        }
        else
        {
            var yaExiste = false;

            for(var i in Jugadores)
            {
                var con = JSON.parse(Jugadores[i]);
                //if(con[i].player === j){
                  //console.log(con[i].player); 
                //}
                if(con.player == jugador){
                    yaExiste = true;
                }
            }
            
            if(yaExiste)
            {
               console.log(con.player);
            }
            else
            {
                var jugador_push = JSON.stringify({
                        "player" : jugador,
                        "score" : 0
                 });
                 Jugadores.push(jugador_push);
                 localStorage.setItem("Jugadores", JSON.stringify(Jugadores));
            }
        }

        console.log(localStorage.getItem("Jugadores"))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Jugadores</p>
  <input id="txtplayer" value=""/>
  <button>Agregar</button>
</div>
```

El problema radica que cuando haces el FOR, recorre el arreglo entero, y eventualmente encuentra alguno que no coincide, entonces lo agrega. Utilizando una bandera `yaExiste = false` Nos permite revisar el arreglo y ya que vimos que ya existe, no agregarlo, y en caso contrario agregarlo. Espero este claro, sino cualquier duda avisame :)

**No funcione el codigo aquí por el localstorage, te dejo el [link](https://codepen.io/tppshaka77/pen/zaoebv) del Codepen

Comment: Funciono a la perfección, muchas gracias amigo

Comment: Me alegra que así fuera. con todo gusto! :)